# error while rendering a partial in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial in rails using the normal

```
<%=render 'subtasks/descform %> command
```

Now the issue is that this descform partial is being called from inside another partial which is 'subtasks/subtask' and their are many subtasks.

So the subtask partial is also getting rendered from the task partial like this

```
<% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
<%=render :partial=>subtask %>
<%end%>
```

So the problem is in the desc form,it has a form like this

```
<%=form_for subtask,:remote=>:true,:method => :put do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :description,rows:'5',cols:'12',:class=>'myarea'%>
          <%= f.submit "save",class:'btn btn-success col-md-4' %>
         <a data-id='<%=subtask.id %>' href="#" class="myclose"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="margin:10px auto;"></i></a>
<% end %>
```

So,when i am trying to render this form i am getting an error

undefined local variable or method `subtask' for #<#:0x458f6b8>

Can somebody please explain the cause of this error and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the variable to the partial, like so:

```
<%=render 'subtasks/descform', :subtask => subtask %>
```

Then it will be accessible in your partial as `subtask`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `subtask` object as a local variable to `descform` partial. First to subtask partial and then to descform

```
<% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
   <%=render :partial => 'subtask', :locals => {:subtask => subtask} %>
<%end%>
```

And inside `subtask` partial, pass it on to `descform`

```
 <%=render :partial => 'subtasks/descform', :locals => {:subtask => subtask} %>
```

You have to mention `partial` when you pass in locals. For eg, the following will not work

```
<%=render 'subtasks/descform', :locals => {:subtask => subtask} %>
```

Comment: tried doin that,not working.still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

In the task partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "subtask", :collection => task.subtasks %>
```

In the subtask partial:

```
<%=render :partial => 'subtasks/descform', :locals => {:subtask => subtask} %>
```

Comment: First, fixed my missing colon. If you pass :locals => {:subtask => subtask} then it certainly shouldn't give an error indicating that there's not such a local variable. Does the error message still indicate missing local variable?